# How to add promise/event when data change is reflected on page?

Tags: angularjs, events, rendering

Consider such scenario -- I have two repeaters A and B on the web page, and a button which calls a function "load_data" when clicked.

That function will load data and on success (promise) it will set two scope variables A and B.

The rest is angular job -- it will notice A or B was changed and it will rerender given repeater.

But I would like to add post-action to that -- a promise, or event, the name is not important, any mechanism in general that notify me that all renderings on my variables A **and** B are finished.

*Background story is thin in my case -- I have to measure the sizes and positions of several elements after they are rendered. I found a directive ( http://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/03/angularjs-after-render-directive/ ) which basically adds event "after-render" but it is element oriented and works for selected element. While I am looking for something more data oriented, data were used, **all** elements were updated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the scope is updated (and if you're within Angular digest cycle, otherwise you may need to `$apply` the scope), Angular will update the DOM in the same synchronous stack.

This means that any code executed asynchronously will be executed after Angular is done digesting. So you can use `setTimeout` or `$timeout`:

```
mypromise.then(function() {

  $scope.model = 'updated';

  $timeout(function() {
    // This code will be executed after DOM has been updated
  });

})
```

Comment: I am sorry for late reply, nevertheless I am grateful for your help. I am happy the solution is so simple, thank you very much for the explanation as well!